# Tamron 70-200 f/2.8 autofocus lagging

Tags: autofocus

I took my lens out to my first gig as I am a local band photographer. I took some photos in auto and most in manual. It seems there's a little lag in the autofocus or am I doing something wrong. I have a Nikon D5300 which is compatible. The autofocus seems to bounce in and out. Do I need to set a different focal point? Any suggestions would be helpful

Tamron 70-200mm f/2.8 Di LD Macro lens (model N001).

Comment: As a concert photographer, I can tell you music photography is HARD and the lighting can play all sorts of havoc with metering and auto focus. Are you having the same problem in other  'easier' conditions (such as outside on a sunny day)

Comment: Is this when using the regular viewfinder or the Live View screen?  Sounds like Live View, which is substantially slower than focus in the viewfinder (contrast vs phase detection, etc).

Answer (score 2):

That lens is well known to be a fairly slow focuser. Pretty much every review I've ever seen about it says so.